# How can I fix api error on android studio?

Tags: apk, http-toolkit

An application Ive been using for months on android studio suddenly got updated and it stopped working. I was using it with https toolkit to check data off of it. I had patched it previously with the toolkit certificate and it worked fine until now when it returns error: "check your API configuration"

[image: error]

2 other apps that's also patched continues to work fine. Tinkering with it, I discovered the app is rejecting the adb global proxy settings. I removed it and app started to work again suggesting despite the apk already patched with the toolkit certificate, its somehow still detecting the proxy on 8001 port and rejecting it. I hope someone can help me with this issue.

Comment: UI error message like the one you have posted are lacking all necessary information to identify the root cause. Better check `adb logcat` for error messages and stack traces of that app. In your case it may be e.g. because the app implements certificate pinning, then you ange to patch more than just modifying the network security configuration.

Comment: Im frequently getting:
`'Setting back callback OnBackInvokedCallbackInfo{mCallback=android.window.IOnBackInvokedCallback$Stub$Proxy@b3263f3, mPriority=0}
  1087  1087 D CarrierSvcBindHelper: onPackageModified:`

before the app's splash screen display error on logcat.

When you mention certificate pinning, do you mean using frida to overcome the apps certificate pinning?